# Issue with alignof in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am not able to understand why the following program fails compilation on Visual Studio 2019 C++? There is no details about the error in output except the minimal **error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << alignof('c');

  return 0;
}
```

Log output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: X6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>temp.cpp
1>C:\Users\Exercises\temp.cpp(10,19): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
1>Done building project "X6.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried to use online C++ compiler and it fails for VC++ but passes for GCC. What am I doing wrong?

GCC: https://rextester.com/EVMZ74126

VC++: https://rextester.com/OAEW69331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [alignof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) expects a type name, for example `char`, but you are providing a literal `'c'` instead. Try `alignof(char)` instead.